# Cerrar sesion con php

Tags: php, sesiones

Buenas estoy haciendo una pagina web y estoy usando sesiones para que no se pueda entrar en ciertas partes de la web como por ejemplo la administración si no se esta logueado, el problema es que solo he sabido cerrar la sesión de dos formas:
Con un enlace a un archivo que cierra la sesión o cerrando completamente el navegador, ¿habria alguna forma de que al cerrar todas las pestañas de mi pagina se cerrara la sesión?

Comment: en el archivo que invocas en tu primer opción tienes en uso `session_destroy()` ?

Comment: Ahora si buscas liberar todas las variables que estés ocupando en tu sesión, además de la primera que te mencioné deberás agregar `session_unset();`

Comment: solo uso la funcion de unset, el problema de esto es que para cerrar sesión asi el usuario tiene que pinchar el botón para ello, si cierra la venta y entra otra vez la sesión sigue iniciada